What does "running stuff" refer to?
In Barbie (2023), Ken was upset because President Barbie declared the reinstatement
of the Barbie Constitution and the unbrainwashing of all affected Barbies:

Ken: I'm a liberated man. I know crying is not weak.
Barbie: Okay. You wanna sit up for a minute?
Ken: This, uh...It was hard running stuff. I didn't love it.

What does "running stuff" refer to ?

stuff = (unspecified) things

You are supposed to look words up in a dictionary before asking a question here.

“To run” something can mean to “manage” or “oversee”, like “running a company” (overseeing the company’s operations; being in charge); or even “running an errand” (doing a small task).
Wiktionary, “run”:

(transitive) To control or manage; to be in charge of. My uncle ran a
corner store for forty years. She runs the fundraising. My parents
think they run my life. He is running the candidate's expensive
campaign.

So when Ken says “It was hard running stuff”, he means it was hard being in charge, or taking care of all the general matters he had to attend to, as the leader of Barbieland. He’s admitting he might be glad Barbie is back in charge.
